# Changing y min max values

Tags: vba, excel

Hey guys Im trying to change my y-min and y-max values on my chart as well as make sure all of the tick labels are forced to be shown. Any suggestions on how to do that with this code in mind?

This is part of a userform

```
Sub MakeFinanceChart()

Dim rX1 As Range rY1 As Range, rX2 As Range, rY2 As Range, rX3 As Range, rY3 As Range, rX4 As Range, rY4 As Range, rX5 As Range, rY5 As Range, rX6 As Range, rY6 As Range
Dim rChartPos As Range
Dim chtO As ChartObject

Set rX1 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C80"): Set rY1 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("F5:F80")
Set rX2 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C80"): Set rY2 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("J5:J80")
Set rX3 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C80"): Set rY3 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("L5:L80")
Set rX4 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C80"): Set rY4 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("P5:P80")
Set rX5 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C80"): Set rY5 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("T5:T80")
Set rX6 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("C5:C80"): Set rY6 = Worksheets("Finance").Range("X5:X80")

Set rChartPos = Worksheets("PLOTS").Range("O2:X28") ' location and dimensions of the chart
With rChartPos
Set chtO = .Parent.ChartObjects.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
chtO.Name = "Finance Plots"
End With

'Plot the Whole Finance CHART

With chtO.Chart

    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

    ' First series
    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = rX1
        .Values = rY1
        .Name = "A"
    End With

    ' Second series
    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = rX2
        .Values = rY2
         .Name = "B"
   End With

    ' Third series
    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = rX3
        .Values = rY3
         .Name = "C"
   End With

   ' Fourth series
    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = rX4
        .Values = rY4
        .Name = "D"
    End With

    ' Fifth series
    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = rX5
        .Values = rY5
         .Name = "E"
   End With

    ' Sixth Series
    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = rX6
        .Values = rY6
         .Name = "F"
   End With


    .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Finance Plot"

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: Can I help you further?

Comment: That was perfect! You can help me a little further. I have another question on a related matter on my account page. Can you see if you can help with that one too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Near the bottom of your code, just below where you assign the chart title, add this bit of code:

```
    With .Axes(xlValue)
        .MinimumScale = 0
        .MaximumScale = 100
        .MajorTickMark = xlOutside
        .MinorTickMark = xlOutside
    End With
```

You can supply your own Min and Max axis scale values. If you do not want the tiny ticks just remove the MinorTickMarck line.